# What is the best way to calculate if today is an upcoming anniversary (based on some start date)?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have some code that get a date:

```
 DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2010, 1,4);
```

and I want to create a function

```
 string message = CalculateUpcomingAnniversary(startDate);
```

and I am trying to calculate if today is possibly an upcoming anniversary

So if there anniversary is coming up in the next 5 days (given this start date), I want to have a function that returns something like  "3 year anniversary coming up in 4 days . . ."

for anything else i just want to return empty string.  What is the most efficient way to calculate this?

So given this start date above, if I ran it today it would return a blank string, but if i ran this function on Jan 5th, 2014, it would return a string "**4 year anniversary in 1 day**"

Comment: what does `startDate` variable represents here?

Comment: @bland Shortest version of "What have you tried so far?" I've ever seen.

Comment: @Sachin - I updated the question to be a bit clearer . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to split this in to two functions. First find the next anniversary like this:

```
public DateTime GetNextAnniversary(DateTime startDate)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now
    var next = startDate.AddYears(now.Year - startDate.Year);
    return now > next ? next.AddYears(1) : next;
}
```

You can this format the date like this:

```
public string GetAnniversaryString(DateTime startDate)
{
    var next = GetNextAnniversary(startDate);
    int nYears = next.Year - startDate.Year;
    var span = next - DateTime.Now;
    return span.Days <= 5 
        ? string.Format("{0} year anniversary in {1} days", nYears, span.Days)
        : string.Empty;
}
```

Or perhaps a more complete method would look something like this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var next = GetNextAnniversary(startDate);
int nYears = next.Year - startDate.Year;
var span = next - DateTime.Now;
if (span.Days <= 30)
{
    return string.Format("{0} year anniversary in {1} days", nYears, span.Days);
}
else
{
    int months = next.Month - startDate.Month;
    if (next.Year > now.Year)
    {
        months += CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(now.Year);
    }

    return string.Format("{0} year anniversary in {1} months", nYears, months);
}
```

Of course this is a pretty crude string formatting function, and could be improved significantly.

Comment: I updated the question as maybe i wasn't clear.   I am not looking to find the anniversary . . I and trying to calculate if today is an upcoming anniversary given some start date.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @leora This is mostly pseudocode to give you the general idea of how you might implement it yourself. You'd want to implement this as a function, so presumably it would be a parameter.

Comment: I see . . the one issue i have is what if startdate happened to be a leap year and the start date was Feb 29, 2012.  I think your GetNextAnniversary function would blow up as it would try to create a date for Feb 29, 2013 which doesn't exists

Comment: when you have now.Years, do you really mean now.Year ??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the following (it checks for the <5-days advance notification, as per requirement):

```
DateTime _now = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan _ts = _now - startDate;

// days till anniversary
if(_ts.Days>5) return null;

// next anniversary, intermediate result
DateTime _nextAnniversary = new DateTime(_now.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day);

// next anniversary, final result
return (_now > _nextAnniversary )? _nextAnniversary.AddYears(1):_nextAnniversary;
```

This code snippet can be encapsulated into complete function, which may return either both  `_ts.Days` and `_nextAnniversary` values (then you should define some struct or object to return), or just `_nextAnniversary`, because days ahead could be easily calculated as shown in the code (`_ts.Days`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetAnniversarydate();   


        }

 protected void GetAnniversarydate()
        { 
         DateTime _anniversarydate = new DateTime(2005, 6, 9);

            DateTime _currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

            //Comparing the anniversary day and month with current day and month
            if ((_anniversarydate.Day == _currentdate.Day) && (_anniversarydate.Month == _currentdate.Month))
            {
                int _Yeardifference = _currentdate.Year - _anniversarydate.Year;

                Response.Write(string.Format("Today is your {0} anniversary",_Yeardifference));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounded like an interesting problem, so I solved it. I also handled leap years messing with the day countand this tests it to prove it. Here you go:

EDIT: Fixed and simplified.

```
public class AnniversaryConcept : IConceptable
{
    public const int DAYS_TO_LOOK_FORWARD = 5;

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(6, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(5, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(4, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(3, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(1, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(0, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(-1, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(-2, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(-3, -1)));

        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -1)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -2)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -3)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -4)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -5)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -6)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -7)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -8)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -9)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -10)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -11)));
        Console.WriteLine(AnniversaryMessage(GetPastDate(2, -12)));
    }

    private DateTime GetPastDate(int daysOffset, int yearsOffset)
    {
        return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).AddYears(yearsOffset).AddDays(daysOffset);
    }

public string AnniversaryMessage(DateTime originalDate)
{
    if (originalDate > DateTime.Now)
    {
        return null;
    }

    int dayDifference = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, originalDate.Month, originalDate.Day).Date
                                    - DateTime.Now.Date).Days;

    // Already past this date.
    if (dayDifference < 0 || dayDifference > DAYS_TO_LOOK_FORWARD)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return string.Format("{0} year anniversary in {1} days.", 
        DateTime.Now.Year - originalDate.Year, 
        dayDifference);
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  For example if you have the startdate May 8th, 2013 . .it returns 14 years in 1 day instead of 13 years today . .

Comment: @leora I hate leaving a bad answer. This should be fixed. You can see the dates I've tested it for in my Run() method, which is there to prove  it works. This takes in a date and lets you know if there is an anniversary coming up as of DateTime.Now. If you don't want it to use DateTime.Now, add another DateTime parameter and send it in, then use that instead of DateTime.Now.